# Integration of Coded UI

Tags: perl, integration, coded-ui-tests

Is it possible to integrate coded UI with any other scripting languages?

Since Coded UI doesn't support many custom controls and third party controls, it would be better if we could integrate coded UI with scripting, like Perl scripting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official support for Pearl script from microsoft. But you can integrate it with VB script. For your kind information, CodedUI does support all the HTML and WIN custom controls, and partially supports the 3rd party controls like KendoUI, Telerik. You just need to produce the correct properties.. Good luck !!

Answer (score 0):

We have switched to using FlaUI, https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI, to handle our Coded UI. We use C# so I'm not sure if it is usable by other languages but it is very helpful.